# Syntax error when printing with string replacement

Tags: python, machine-learning, syntax

I'm using this code to calculate an accuracy score that I want to print

```
accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(predictions,data[outcome])
print "Accuracy :%s" % "{0:.3%}".format(accuracy)
```

But when I run my code I get the below error.

```
  File "<ipython-input-53-a86f8606658d>", line 19
    print "Accuracy :%s" % "{0:.3%}".format(accuracy)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You need to add `python3` tag to make your question clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print("Accuracy :{0:.3%}".format(accuracy))
```

Demo:

```
accuracy = 0.83456789
print("Accuracy :{0:.3%}".format(accuracy))
```

prints:

```
Accuracy :83.457%
```

Comment: Ooops I got my mistake
Thanks(y)